Repairing the Gospels
What are the halachic considerations if one is a book binder and a client wishes to hire him or her to repair a Christian bible? The bible isn't directly used in Avodah Zarah (for those who see Christianity as such) but it effects Avodah Zarah in a way.
I have seen questions about selling items which might be used for Avodah Zarah but I'm not sure that the same issues are in play. Any established discussions or piskei halacha would be welcome but at least some help in issue spotting. (does it make a difference if the person repairs the book for pay vs. as a favor? Or the nature and permanence of the repair? Or if the person asking is a private citizen vs. being a clergy member or representative of a group?)

I made an adjustment to broaden the question a bit, and I suspect it aligns with your original intentions. Apologies if not, feel free to revert of course
